# Magento Cart API not showing prices

Tags: api, magento, xml-rpc

I am attempting to use the Magento Enterprise 1.10 XML-RPC API to handle cart/catalog functions outside of the Magento installation. The issue that I am having is when I add to cart. I can connect just fine to the API endpoint, login, and retrieve data. The following is the code that I am using to discover the workings of the Magento API.

```
<?php    
   require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php';

   $url = 'http://mymagento.com/api/xmlrpc';
   $user = 'apiuser';
   $pass = 'apipass';

   $proxy = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client( $url );
   $sess = $proxy->call( 'login', array( $user, $pass ) );
   $cartId = $proxy->call( 'call', array( $sess, 'cart.create', array( 1 ) ) );

   $pList = $proxy->call( 'call', array( $sess, 'product.list', array() ) );
   $cList = $proxy->call( 'call', array( $sess, 'customer.list', array() ) );

   $cList[0]['mode'] = 'customer';

   $setCart = $proxy->call( 'call', array( $sess,
      'cart_customer.set',
      array( $cartId, $cList[0] ) ) );

   foreach( $pList as $prod)
   {
      if( $prod['product_id'] == 5 )
      {
          $prod['qty'] = 5;
          $addCart = $proxy->call( 'call', array( $sess, 
              'cart_product.add',
              array( $cartId, $pAdd ) ) );
      }
   }

   $cList = $proxy->call( 'call', array( $sess, 'cart.info', array( $cartId ) ) );
   print_r( $cList );
```

Outputs:

```
[store_id] => 1
[created_at] => 2011-05-27 13:30:57
[updated_at] => 2011-05-27 13:31:00
[converted_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
[is_active] => 0
[is_virtual] => 0
[is_multi_shipping] => 0
[items_count] => 1
[items_qty] => 5.0000
[orig_order_id] => 0
[store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000
[store_to_quote_rate] => 1.0000
[base_currency_code] => USD
[store_currency_code] => USD
[quote_currency_code] => USD
[grand_total] => 0.0000
[base_grand_total] => 0.0000
[checkout_method] => customer
...
[items] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 93
            [quote_id] => 119
            [created_at] => 2011-05-27 13:31:00
            [updated_at] => 2011-05-27 13:31:00
            [product_id] => 5
            [store_id] => 1
            [parent_item_id] => 
            [is_virtual] => 1
            [sku] => product1
            [name] => product
            [description] => 
            [applied_rule_ids] => 
            [additional_data] => 
            [free_shipping] => 0
            [is_qty_decimal] => 0
            [no_discount] => 0
            [weight] => 
            [qty] => 5
            [price] => 0.0000
            [base_price] => 0.0000
            [custom_price] => 
            [discount_percent] => 0.0000
            [discount_amount] => 0.0000
            [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
```

However, I am to just call the following using the same above session

```
<?php
    $pInfo = $proxy->call( 'call', array( $sess, 'catalog_product.info', '5' ) );
    print_r( $pInfo );
```

I get the following information about the product:

```
[product_id] => 5
[sku] => product1
[set] => 9
[type] => virtual
[categories] => Array
    (
    )

[websites] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[type_id] => virtual
[name] => product
[description] => Test
[short_description] => Test
[news_from_date] => 
[old_id] => 
[news_to_date] => 
[status] => 1
[visibility] => 4
...
[created_at] => 2011-05-25 15:11:34
[updated_at] => 2011-05-25 15:11:34
...
[price] => 10.0000
```

In the end, the API sees that the price of the item is in fact $10.00, but when added to the cart via API the prices are not properly reflected.

Comment: solution found, http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/227044/ I spent two days searching for this, and today come up with an obscure search term to try and find the solution.

Comment: You can answer your own questions and close this out, FYI.

Comment: I dont have high enough contribution, can't answer it for 4 more hours. =\

Answer (score 6):

Just so it can be an officially answered question, here is the solution found, http://magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/227044 I spent two days searching for this, and today come up with an obscure search term to try and find the solution

Comment: the link in your answer was changed and doesn't point to the solution any more. this one does: https://web.archive.org/web/20120624021427/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/227044

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at this issue for a couple days now. It didn't make sense to me that if you add a product to your cart through the normal web interface [ie `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()` ]. It knows the price without you providing an address. I finally found the difference between the two. In `addAction()` they create an instance of `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart`, add the product to that, and save it. In the api they use `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` instead. If you look at `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::save()` you will see these two lines:

```
$this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
```

These two lines actually create empty `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` objects that get saved into the db.

If you are willing/able to modify magento's code, you can modify `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Api::create()` and add a call to these two methods before `$quote->save()` and the api and the web interface will work the same way.

I have only tested this a little bit, but I really think this is a bug and not a feature. I'll see about getting this in front of actual magento devs and maybe they'll include it in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Magento frontend and API both are different. In frontend after registering customer it creates quote for customer and also set address with that created quote id. But in API it creates only quote using `shoppingCartCreate` service. For proper we need to customize create service. I did and it worked for me.

Here am providing solution:

Edit function in file - `Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart/Api.php`

```
public function create($store = null)
{
    $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);

    try {
        /*@var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote*/
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
        $quote->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setIsActive(false)
                ->setIsMultiShipping(false)
                ->save();

/* Customized this for saving default address for quote and it will show price in cart info*/
 $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $quote->collectTotals();
    $quote->save();

/* End cart here */

    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('create_quote_fault', $e->getMessage());
    }
    return (int) $quote->getId();
}
```